# System.Linq.Dynamic returning Json of collection of objects from dynamic table search, result gives a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I am using System.Linq.Dynamic to make a search on dynamic table, column, and value. The result returns correct values. The problem is i am not sure why i can not just return that var as Json to the front and as i did with other dynamic searches. Even if i do not do a dynamic search i am unable to pass to front end the result query object as Json.

```
using (db)
{
    var res = context.Sets(table_name)
                          .AsQueryable()
                          .Where(where, part_search)
                          .Select("new(item1, item2, item3)").Take(50);
    return Json(res);
}
```

POST http://localhost:52498/Controller/Action 500 (Internal Server Error)

Would appreciate the help.

Comment: maybe debug server side and see what is the error?

Comment: There is no error. I stored it now as var test = Json(res); then serialized the var test into string stringtest. Then returned Json(stringtest); and it worked. No idea why though....The problem with this though i need array of all the objects(top 50). This will return only last result. And i do not want to iterate through collection of objects. So need to figure out what is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why it does not let me but i did work around. I formatted result as Json which is Json object(which if sent directly gives me the 500 error), then serialize it to make it in to a string, then turned it back into Json which is now a single long string. Seems redundant...

asp.NET MVC Controller:

```
JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var resJson= Json(res);
string resJsonString= ser.Serialize(resJson.Data);
return Json(resJsonString);
```

This worked and front end receives a the data from POST ajax which is not in format i want though. So i simply parsed the string which was one long Json string...that gave me Json object with arrays and keys like i wanted. No idea why it would work this way but not directly as with other methods.

asp.net MVC View:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/Controller/Action",
    data: {data: "search"},
    success: function(data){
      var data = JSON.parse(data)
      var keys = Object.keys(data[0])
   }
})
```

If someone can explain it to me i would appreciate it. 
Thank you